# MVC 4 Razor adding input type date

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering how to insert a `<input type="date"/>` for datetime attributes of my model. 
As for now Razor creates a plain input element with `type="datetime"`. I want to make use of the new input types of HTML5.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I managed to do it by using the following code.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { type = "time" })
```

Comment: Just a late comment why this answer shows only time in Chrome?

Comment: Input type date isn't supported in Safari or IE. Were you using either of those? Source: https://caniuse.com/#search=date

Comment: Html.EditorFor should be used instead textboxfor

Answer (score 53):

The input date value format needs the date specified as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6 full-date.

So I've ended up doing:

```
<input type="date" id="last-start-date" value="@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.LastStartDate)" />
```

I did try doing it "properly" using:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime LastStartDate
{
    get { return lastStartDate; }
    set { lastStartDate = value; }
}
```

with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastStartDate, 
    new { type = "date" })
```

Unfortunately that always seemed to set the value attribute of the input to a standard date time so I've ended up applying the formatting directly as above.

**Edit:**

According to Jorn if you use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastStartDate)
```

instead of TextBoxFor it all works fine.

Comment: +1 Actually, it seems that with these data annotations on the property, `Html.EditorForm(m => m.LastStartDate)` renders an `<input type=date>`. Thus, no need to override the `type` attribute.

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode Thanks.  Shouldn't that be Html.EditorFor?

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode I've updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Indeed it should. The `m` is a typo :)

Comment: Where does EditorFor come from?

Comment: @tofutim EditorFor comes from System.Web.Mvc.Html.

Comment: Note that the example using TextBoxFor will give you an input control with a date picker by default. Using editor will give you a date input without the date picker functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntryDate, new{ type = "date" })

 or type = "time"

 it will display a calendar
 it will not work if you give @Html.EditorFor()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use @Html.EditorFor() you have to use jQuery ui and 
update your Asp.net Mvc to 5.2.6.0 with NuGet Package Manager.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EntryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

@section Scripts {

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.datepicker').datepicker();

     });

</script>
```

}

Answer (score -3):

You will get it by tag type="date"...then it will render beautiful calendar and all...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { type = "date" })
```