# How to set value into HTML5 date field from Asp.Net MVC Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423888/mvc-4-razor-adding-input-type-date) but that do not work for my case. Please look at the screen shot below. When I render data in an Edit form, all data was set to the controls properly except the highlighted date field. When I inspect the element, I found that the value is there but for some reason it is not showing in the field.

Here is the code I used to set value into this date field. I tried both **"yyyy-MM-dd"** & **"MM/dd/yyyy"** format but none worked.

```
<td>Joining Date</td>
<td>
@{
   if(Model.JoiningDate != null)
   {
      <input id="txtJoiningDate" type="date" style="width: 100%;" value="@String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",Model.JoiningDate.Value)" />
   }
   else
   {
      <input id="txtJoiningDate" type="date" style="width: 100%;" />
   }
}
</td>
```

[image]

**Edit**
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why instead you just use html helper as shown :-

```
@Html.TextBox("txtJoiningDate", Model.JoiningDate.Value ,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",new{ @style="width:100%", type="date" })
```

Comment: I tried replacing 'v' with 'V' too, but the result is same :(

Comment: if I go with the 1st option, will it be possible to get the value of this control (as the value can be changed by the user) using jquery? If yes, then how can I do that? AS of now, I am getting this value using jquery i.e. $("#txtJoiningDate").val() ; that is using an id for this control

Comment: @V.P.Verma...if you see in console..the html generated by first answer will be same as you have given in your question..don't worry about that..

Comment: Well, yes, but in that case, the control is loosing the "Calender" that I want the user to see for selecting a date. Although, using first option is displaying a plain TextBox with correct value, but it also looses the Calender functionality. Any way around for that?

Comment: `MM/dd/yyyy` format won't work. It has to be ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Okk..Okk..due to type='date' which is a html5 attribute it is creating problem..right..???....@Mrchief

Comment: @Exception, yes, I have to change the format from "MM/dd/yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd". But thanks to both you and "Mrchief" for helping me :D

Answer (score 10):

For Html5 input type="date" fields, the values must be specified in the format "yyyy-MM-dd". Once you set it in that format, you will see the value assigned on screen.

Comment: I applied this to my code-behind and it was the solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

using  Html   helper

```
@Html.TextBox("txtJoiningDate", Model.JoiningDate.Value ,"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

In Model

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> JoiningDate{ get; set; }
```

This is works for me

Comment: where you mentioned input type="date" ?

Answer (score 2):

You sure you tried yyyy-MM-dd format? Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/vawdmax1/1/), works properly on Chrome

```
<input id="txtJoiningDate" type="date" style="width: 100%;" value="2010-12-25" /> -> works

<input id="txtJoiningDate" type="date" style="width: 100%;" value="2010/12/25" /> -> will not work
```

Comment: yes. Please look into the 2nd image in edit section. Even in Chrome, it is not showing properly.

Comment: I'm presuming your browser version is fairly recent. Other thing I can think of is maybe some other plugin/JS is interfering. Does the demo work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.JoiningDate)
```

also in your model:

```
    [DisplayName("Joining date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? JoiningDate { get; set; }
```